# In Mercury, why can't I use a state variable in a function application?

Tags: mercury

When describing state variables, the Mercury [reference manual](https://mercurylang.org/information/doc-release/reference_manual.pdf) says: "`!X` may not appear as an argument in a function application, since this would not make sense given the usual interpretation of state variables and functions" (p. 14). I'd like to understand that reasoning better: What is it about state variables and functions that makes the combination nonsensical?

Part of my confusion comes from the code below, where I'm able to use the `!.X, !:X` form of state variables, but not the `!X` form. If I can use the former, why not the latter?

This code compiles, and runs as expected:

```
% Choose values, A and B, from the list of values, subject to certain restrictions
:- pred pick_a_b(int, int, list(int), list(int)).
:- mode pick_a_b(out, out, in,        out) is nondet.
pick_a_b(A, B, !Values) :-
    A = pick(!.Values, !:Values),
    B = pick(!.Values, !:Values),
    A \= 3, A > 2, B > 2, B \= 4.

% Choose any item from the input list; pass all the un-chosen items back to the caller.
:- func pick(list(int), list(int)) = int.
:- mode pick(in,        out)       = out is nondet.
pick([X | Xs], Xs)      = X.
pick([X | Xs], [X | Zs]) = pick(Xs, Zs).

main(!IO) :-
    if 
        Values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        pick_a_b(A, B, Values, _)
    then
        io.format("A = %i\n", [i(A)], !IO),
        io.format("B = %i\n", [i(B)], !IO)
    else
        io.format("Something went wrong\n", [], !IO).
```

But changing the first two lines of `pick_a_b` results in compile errors.

```
pick_a_b(A, B, !Values) :-
    A = pick(!Values),
    B = pick(!Values),
    A \= 3, A > 2, B > 2, B \= 4.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "function" pick has a strange mode, (in, out) = out.  This is very unusual and this is why the !:Values syntax works in your first example.  It normally wouldn't as functions normally have the mode (in, in, ..., in) = out.

The reference manual is correct in saying that the !X syntax doesn't make sense in a function call, I also believe that your use of !:Values and your function's mode do not make sense either.  Yes your code is legal and the compiler accepts it and can compile it, however I don't know why anyone would use a function here rather than a predicate. Doing so is likely to confuse people reading your code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The usual interpretation of state variables is that one of the pair is an input and the other is an output, and the usual interpretation of functions is that all of the arguments are inputs and the return value is an output. The reference manual is pointing out that, given these interpretations, using a state variable as an argument does not make sense.

The reasoning might be summarized as: just because you *can* allow a programmer to write something, doesn't mean you *should*.